# How to debug "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['" in PHP?

Tags: php

I am getting this error:

> line: 41, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/acompanh/public_html/novosite/vipmin/team/index.php on line 41

PHP file:

```
 <?php
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$HTTP_REFERER = '';
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$document = '';
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$server = '';
$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$ip = '';
$retorno = 'libera';

if ($retorno != 'libera') {
    echo $retorno;
    exit(  );
}

require_once( dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) . '/app.php' );
need_manager(  );
need_auth( 'team' );
$now = '';

if ($_REQUEST['acao'] == 'site') {
    $condition = array( '' . 'end_time > ' . $now );
}

strval( $_GET['team_title'] );
$team_title = '';
strval( $_GET['city_id'] );

if ($city_id) {
    $condition['city_id'] = $city_id;
}


if ($team_title) {
    $condition[] = 'title LIKE \'%' . mysql_escape_string( $team_title ) . '%\'';
}

Table::count( 'team', $condition );
$count = '';
pagestring( $count, 20 )[2];
$pagestring = time(  );
[1];
$offset = ;
[0];
$pagesize = ;
DB::limitquery( 'team', array( 'condition' => $condition, 'order' => 'ORDER BY id DESC', 'size' => $pagesize, 'offset' => $offset ) );
$teams = ;
Table::fetch( 'category', Utility::getcolumn( $teams, 'city_id' ) );
$cities = $city_id = ;
DB::limitquery( 'partner', array( 'order' => 'ORDER BY id DESC' ) );
$partners = ;
Utility::optionarray( $partners, 'id', 'title' );
$partners = ;
$selector = 'index';
include( template( 'manage_team_index' ) );
?>
```

Comment: what is `[1];` meant to be doing?

Comment: What is `pagestring( $count, 20 )[2]` doing? You are calling a function, dereferencing the array result, and the throwing the result away.

Comment: A better title will attract more attention, and accurate tags are helpful as well. This problem is nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: I wonder if someone has done a search and replace on this code, made an error, and left it in a broken state?

Comment: Array dereferencing was only introduced in PHP 5.4

Answer (score 4):

You need to learn to debug and read your own code:

```
[1];   <--- array shortcut declaration not being assigned anywhere
$offset = ;
          ^---missing value
[0];  <--- array shortcut declaration not being assigned anywhere
$pagesize = ;
           ^---missing value
$teams = ;
         ^--missing value
```

These errors are rampant throughout your code

Comment: Marc, i'm fixing line by line and i found an error just line 41, i solve my problem. Tks a lot

Answer (score 2):

[Array dereferencing](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) is only available in PHP 5.4 and above. Assign the function's return value to a temporary variable and get the value from there.

Edit: on second glance, this code is totally broken. Why is `[1];` on a line by itself? `$pagesize = ;`???

Comment: it took you two whole glances? goodness. i only needed half a glance.

Comment: An upvote for miken's extra glances, then!

Comment: Erm, I'm on my phone. That's my excuse and I'm sticking to it!